# iTunes crashes after playing certain files

Tags: itunes, crash

I can't exactly remember when this started to happen, probably after a software update, but my iTunes suddenly can't play 2 songs and 2 videos (apparently only these). When I try to play them, iTunes freezes and shuts itself down. The iTunes version I currently have is  11.04, running in a Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bits.

The videos were downloaded from the iTunes store, so far I've only tried to delete them from my library and tried to put them back again, but to no avail. When I open them with another software, like WMP, they show no problem at all.

The same applies to the songs, except that they were legally downloaded from a streaming software. I've also tried to change file name, location, copied file, and the same thing happens.

I've also tried to uninstall and reinstall iTunes, but had the same results. Also, I should mention that despite that the videos are now in the iCloud, iTunes keeps crashing when I try to play them as well, so it's certainly not a file problem.

Edit: I've now realised that instead of being certain files, iTunes doesn't play some artists/bands. How can I solve this?

Comment: Which songs and videos? Did you download them from iTunes?

Comment: The videos were downloaded from the iTunes Store, the songs weren't.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the version of the operating system; the content of the .crash file (you can review this in Console); whether you have used Disk Utility to verify the file system and/or permissions; the model of the Mac; and any other details that may help towards an answer.

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question. The information provided is to generic.